# Confused by latest ASP.NET Core 6 React SPA template with individual authentication

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, single-page-application, asp.net-core-identity, duende

I think this could be reproduced on any .NET 6 capable machine, within 1-2 minutes...

**Context**

I am trying the get work the ASP.NET Core 6 React SPA template with Identity authentication.
Based on the [Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which is updated a few days ago I had run:

```
dotnet new react -au Individual
```

I did not modify the application, according the corresponding web page, it is not necessary.
As far I understand, the MVC part is providing the UI for sign-in + have a protected API for Weather.

The app launches, and I successfully register a new user, and successfully log in and out. The UI for this is provided by MS Identity within the application, backed by `Duende.IdentityServer` assemblies. The client React SPA also seems working, for example Counter page works.

However the only interesting part (for me), the JWT, where the React SPA calls the API after acquired a valid JWT token does not work. This is the Fetch data page.

Debugging with Fiddler, I see the HTTP 401, with `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://localhost:44412' is invalid"`

Although I understand what this mean, both the React App and both the API runs on https://localhost:44412, who else could be the expected issuer than https://localhost:44412?

Also the dozens page article not even mentions any necessary modification in the generated template.

**Question**

What am I missing here. Obviously I am not an authentication expert, the whole idea would be to quickly got and idea by learning from a working best practice example...

Comment: have a look at [github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#aspnet-core)

Comment: Many thx, that's an answer. In case you copy the few sentences in that paragraph, and also put the original link, I am going to accept it as an answer.